# Intellij plugin cannot find icon path

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I am trying to add an icon for a tool-window plugin that I develop for IntelliJ. I have followed the instructions found [here](https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/reference_guide/work_with_icons_and_images.html) but IntelliJ reports the following exception:

```
ERROR - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - Icon cannot be found in 'icons/icon.png', aClass='interface icons.PluginIcons'
```

My project structure is

```
...
- resources
--- icons
----- icon.png
----- icon@2x.png
----- icon@2x_dark.png
----- icon_dark.png
- src
--- com
----- micbakos
------ LocationToolWindow.java
--- icons
---- PluginIcons.java
...
```

The `PluginIcons` interface:

```
package icons;

import com.intellij.openapi.util.IconLoader;

import javax.swing.*;

public interface PluginIcons {
    Icon EDIT_LOCATION_ICON = IconLoader.getIcon("icons/icon.png");
}
```

And the plugin.xml

```
<extensions defaultExtensionNs="com.intellij">
    <toolWindow
            id="Location Tool"
            anchor="right"
            factoryClass="com.micbakos.LocationToolWindow"
            icon="PluginIcons.EDIT_LOCATION_ICON"/>
  </extensions>
```

**Hint**

The editor seems to recognize the icon and display it on the left pane of the code `Icon EDIT_LOCATION_ICON = IconLoader.getIcon("icons/icon.png");` by the line number and the plugins.xml `icon="PluginIcons.EDIT_LOCATION_ICON"` jumps on the `PluginIcons.java` when I `⌘+click` on it, so everything seems to be connected correctly.

Comment: Is it in the jar, when you package it?

Comment: Good question. How can I see the jar that is created when I compile and run the plugin through the editor?. Although I can see it in the `out` folder

Comment: WinRar and other tools can look into jars, it's just a zip file.

Answer (score 0):

As [Meo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/685796/meo) pointed out to look for the exported jar, I looked for the out folder. IntelliJ seems to package `PluginIcons.class` inside the `icons` package.

So I changed the code of the `PluginIcons.java` to look like this
`Icon EDIT_LOCATION_ICON = IconLoader.getIcon("icon.png");`.

Now the plugin's icon is appeared when I run the code but the code jump does not work when I click on the `"icon.png"`.  ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Or you could probably use an absolute path `"/icons/icon.png"`

Comment: Yes adding a `/` solves the problem too. I feel like and idiot right now